# Extract and count unique hashtags per row from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, counter, series

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a string column `Posts`, something like this:

```
df['Posts']
0       "This is an example #tag1"
1       "This too is an example #tag1 #tag2"
2       "Yup, still an example #tag1 #tag1 #tag3"
```

When I tried using the following code to count the number of hashtags,

```
count_hashtags = df['Posts'].str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts()
```

I get,

```
#tag1             4
#tag2             1
#tag3             1
```

But I need the result to be count of unique hashtags per row, something like this:

```
#tag1             3
#tag2             1
#tag3             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `drop_duplicates` to get rid of duplicate tags per post, and then you can use `value_counts`

```
df.Posts.str.extractall(
    r'(\#\w+)'
).reset_index().drop_duplicates(['level_0', 0])[0].value_counts()
```

shorter alternative where `level=0` is passed to `reset_index`

```
df.Posts.str.extractall(
    r'(\#\w+)'
).reset_index(level=0).drop_duplicates()[0].value_counts()
```

both will output:

```
#tag1    3
#tag3    1
#tag2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution using `itertools.chain` and `collections.Counter`:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(['This is an example #tag1',
               'This too is an example #tag1 #tag2',
               'Yup, still an example #tag1 #tag1 #tag3'])

tags = s.map(lambda x: {i[1:] for i in x.split() if i.startswith('#')})

res = Counter(chain.from_iterable(tags))

print(res)

Counter({'tag1': 3, 'tag2': 1, 'tag3': 1})
```

**Performance benchmarking**

`collections.Counter` is ~2x as fast as `pd.Series.str.extractall` for a large series:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(['This is an example #tag1',
               'This too is an example #tag1 #tag2',
               'Yup, still an example #tag1 #tag1 #tag3'])

def hal(s):
    return s.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')\
            .reset_index(level=0)\
            .drop_duplicates()[0]\
            .value_counts()

def jp(s):
    tags = s.map(lambda x: {i[1:] for i in x.split() if i.startswith('#')})
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable(tags))

s = pd.concat([s]*100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit hal(s)  # 2.76 s per loop
%timeit jp(s)   # 1.25 s per loop
```